# Get pointer of class object

Tags: matlab, class, oop, pointers, object

I have an object `apple` created by my own class in MATLAB:

```
apple = classA();
```

The class looks like this:

```
classdef classA < handle

   properties
       color = 'red';
   end

   methods
      function obj = classA()
          % ...
      end
   end
end
```

The question: How do I get the object or handle pointer of `apple`? I want to search for objects by their properties, like:

```
isprop(eval(mat(i).name),'color')
```

with `mat = whos`. So I need to get the pointer of the object, represented by the struct `mat(i).name`. I just need the reference, not a copy of the desired object. The purpose is this:

If I get the pointer somehow, like

```
ptr_to_apple_object = get_pointer_fct( mat(i).name )
```

then I am able to change the properties of the `apple`-object like:

```
ptr_to_apple_object. color = 'yellow'
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: There are no "pointers" in MATLAB so do you just want to find all variables that point to objects that have a specific property?

Comment: I just need reference for doing things like this: 'ptr.color = 'blue''. But `ptr` is the pointer or reference to the `apple`-object, that I am trying to find.

Comment: MATLAB does not have pointers. Additionally, as it compiles to java, it doesn't even compile to a language that has pointers.

Comment: @EliSadoff What? It doesn't compile to Java...

Comment: @Suever I was under the impression that it compiles to Java because I've had matlab crash before with Java errors popping up.

Comment: Or at least that it runs on the JVM.

Comment: @EliSadoff Only the graphics are Java-based, the rest runs using C/C++/Fortran.

Comment: @Suever Ah sorry. I did not realize. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no good way to find all current objects of a particular class, but you could use `whos` to get a struct about all variables, loop through this and determine which ones have the property you and then modify

```
variables = whos;

for k = 1:numel(variables)
    obj = eval(variables(k).name);

    if isobject(obj) && isprop(obj, 'color')
        obj.color = 'yellow'; 
    end
end
```

If you're looking for a specific class, you can use the `class` field of the output of `whos`

```
is_class = ismember({variables.class}, 'classA');
instances = variables(is_class);

for k = 1:numel(instances)
    obj = eval(instances(k).name);
    obj.color = 'yellow';
end
```

**Update**

Since you are subclassing `handle`, when you assign your instance to a new variable (`obj = val(variables(k).name)` above), it does not create a copy of your instance, but rather a new reference to the same object.

```
b = classA;
c = b;

b.color = 'red';

c.color
%   'red'
```

Comment: This is basically what I have done so far, but I think this creates a copy (`obj`) of my object (`apple`) in the workspace.

Comment: @Lemonbonbon You're using a `handle` class so there is no copy, they both refer to the same object

Comment: AH, okay. I didn`t know that.